# Сложение двух чисел на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Какие функции сложения присутствуют на ассемблере, в частности в NASM'е?

Comment: У Вас слишком общий вопрос. Напишите более конкретно, что не понятно, где сложности.

Comment: Сам процесс сложения, т.е. функции, которые нужны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо помню ассемблер, но вроде все просто

```
mov ax, {переменная, где хранится 1 слагаемое}
add ax, {переменная, где хранится 2 слагаемое}
mov {переменная, где будет ответ}, ax
```

Answer (score 1):

Осмелюсь предположить, что сложение производится командой:
add (к примеру "add ax,bx")